# How would "Rolling a die" work in 4 Dimensions?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, dice

I imagine we could use a Tesseract (4D cube) as a die. It has 24 faces and 8 3-faces.

1. How would it be numbered?
2. Would the "top" 3-face be considered as the output of the die throw?

I am basing the above statements by the following reasoning - In 3D, we use a 3D cube, thrown on a 2D surface and the top 2D face is the result. Similarly, in 2D the die would also be 2D (square), and the output is the side (or the line segment) of the square.

Thank you for answering and please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The question you should first ask yourself is would you be throwing it on a $3D$ space or a $2D$ space (plane)?

Comment: I would assume the "top" 3-face would be the output, yeah. I think that, just like in the 3D case, if you have a tesseract placed on a hyperplane (the $wxy$ plane) affected by gravity (a force in the negative $z$ direction), the only stable arrangements are when two 3-faces are horizontal (one touching the hyperplane and one parallel to it). And I'm not 99% sure, but I think there are only two unique ways to number it (assuming we want opposite 3-faces to sum to $9$), each a mirror image of the other.

Comment: If your four dimensional creatures are into Dungeons and Dragons, you can even throw [a variety of other dies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_4-polytope#Regular_convex_4-polytopes).

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger yea I thought in a similar way, but the interesting point ins numbering. Would each 3-face have a single number or a set of different numbers? Moreover, we way want to number the faces uniquely so 9 would be a small number.

Comment: I would label the eight different 3-Cells of the Tesseract, which would give you the numbers $1, 2, .., 8$ so two opposing ones sum to $9$ as @AkivaWeinberger suggested. Labeling the 24 faces seems to me like labeling the 12 edges of a cube.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Personally I think rolling them on a 2D plane would not be that interesting because then it would be analogous to a 24-sided die in our3D world (example : Pentagonal icositetrahedral die). Furthermore, would the 2-face be "visible" to the 4D creatures? I mean like we don't consider the 3D die balancing on a edge to be valid.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that (just like the 3D die balancing on an edge cannot be stable) balancing the 4D die on a 2D "edge" could not be stable. So don't label the edges.

Comment: Like, think of it this way. The tesseract is $I^4=(I^2)\times(I^2)$. If the first two coordinates are laying on the "table" (the hyperplane), then we can quotient out by that first $I^2$ and see that this is the same as trying to balance a 2D square on a vertex.